# Deserializing JSON child object values into parent object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> using nested converters

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm receiving some oddly formatted JSON that I want to store in a single object. It looks something like this:

```
{
    "parentObject": 
    {
        "id": 123456,
        "pointlessChildObject": 
        {
            "stringThatCouldBeStoredInParent": "test",
            "epochTimeThatCouldBeStoredInParent": "1520452800"
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I thought this would be simple thanks to a solution by Brian Rogers that I found: [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088462/can-i-specify-a-path-in-an-attribute-to-map-a-property-in-my-class-to-a-child-pr)

However, if you implement this solution, you can't use another converter for converting those values into something else at the same time (A nested `[JsonConverter(typeof(SecondsEpochConverter))]` for the epoch time for example). And of course, because this is C#, you can't have a set that's different than your type (convert `int` to `DateTime` in set). I'm trying to add code to Brian's solution such that it calls the nested converter, but now we're getting into ridiculous territory; I'm creating a single use `JSONTextReader` just to have the value passed to the nested converters, and I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this.

Does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: I suggest using custom jsonconverter and check if fields exist, see link to post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Comment: Why not just use a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)?

Comment: I don't get to control what I'm receiving (the data is provided in JSON by a vendor), only how its interpreted and stored.